# Can I use two languages together in WordPress

Tags: language

com blog can I use two languages, lets say I want to have the Language English and other language. I also need my audience to write comments using either in Engish or another language. Is that possible in WordPress!!

Comment: http://wpml.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- [Language Switcher WordPress Plugin](http://www.poplarware.com/downloads/language_switcher)
- [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/)
- [WPML](http://wpml.org/) - the best, but commercial

Comment: Hi Marcin, this one will work for WordPress.org, however for WordPress.com I don't think, we can install a plugin!!